# drag and drop on dynamically created div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop code works perfectly on divs that have been created on the server side however when i create a div using jquery (dynamically) i cannot seem to drop anything into the container...

```
$('.dropcontent').droppable({
            accept: '.item',
            drop: function(ev, ui) {
               /* do something */
            }    
        });

        $(".item").draggable({  
           helper:'clone',
           appendTo: 'body',
           snap: true,
           revert: true

        });

    <div id="row1seo" class="dropcontent" > </div>   // original code on server side
    <div id="row1seo" class="dropcontent ui-droppable"> </div> // the above line becomes this on client side showing it has "binded" with the droppable
    <div id="row2seo" class="dropcontent"></div> // this the dynamically created div which doesn't seem to bind with the droppable. this is created in php file using ajax to retrieve it
```

I have also tried

```
 $(".dropcontent").live('droppable', function() {
......
});
```

doesnt seem to work... any ideas how to fix this ?

thanks

Comment: the dynamically created div is called from a php file using ajax... so its not created suing jquery/js

Comment: just set up a fiddle in, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: too complicated for js fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make the drag function live so it works on generated elements. Too bad jQuery's `live()` function doesnt handle drags and drops, so you have to create one yourself. I use this function for example:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.liveDraggable = function (opts) {
        this.live("mouseover", function() {
            if (!$(this).data("init")) {
                $(this).data("init", true).draggable(opts);
            }
        });
        return $();
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Call it like this:

```
$( "element" ).liveDraggable()
```

You can easily make one for droppable too! GL!

Comment: doesnt work  (function ($) {
    $.fn.liveDraggable = function (opts) {
        this.live("mouseover", function() {
            if (!$(this).data("init")) {
                $(this).data("init", true).draggable(opts);
            }
        });
        return $();
    };
}(jQuery));

        $('.dropcontent').liveDraggable({
now it doesnt even drop in the regular contianer

Comment: Well the function works for drags I use it myself very often, and you can easily rewrite it to droppable, just replace the words..

Comment: Nice man! Good luck, and feel free to come back any time :D And add the answer so that other people can find it when they look for it!

Comment: (function ($) {
    $.fn.liveDroppable = function (opts) {
        this.live("mouseover", function() {
            if (!$(this).data("init")) {
                $(this).data("init", true).droppable(opts);
            }
        });
        return $();
    };
}(jQuery));
     
        $('.dropcontent').liveDroppable({

Comment: live is deprecated in jquery 1.11.x